# directory deleted in different branch doesn't show even in master branch in git

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am learning git commands through tutorials. I have one doubt:

inside a directory, which i want to make git compatible:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit of full repository"
git remote add origin bitbucket_URL
git push -u origin --all
git checkout -b feature/feature1
git rm README.txt
git add .
<didn't commit>
ls => doesn't show README.txt
git checkout master
ls => it also doesn't show README.txt
```

but I had deleted README from feature1 branch NOT from master. why README is not showing up in ls of master branch

PS: But when I commit after adding in feature1 branch and then switch to master branch and then do ls, then README file shows up. Could someone please explain what is happening underneath

Comment: But when I commit after adding in feature1 branch and then switch to master branch and then do ls, then README file shows up. Could someone please explain what is happening underneath...

Comment: You are allowed to carry uncommitted changes around when you `git checkout` some other branch. For details, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you commit, changes are *up in the air*. You moved to master, changes come with you.... if you had committed on the feature branch, if you checkout master, you would see the file show up..... and *no*, it's not a bug, it's a feature (how many times have you started working on the wrong branch? Or tested a few changes on different branches without having to commit to move around? Well, there you go!!!).